# Issue with WebRTC outgoing call (iOS,Kurento)

Tags: ios, webrtc, kurento

I'm fairly new to webrtc, and quite experienced in iOS.

We have a media server setup on AWS (all ports open), with [kurento one2one client](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-one2one-call). Everything is working well when I call from desktop to desktop. when I call from desktop to iOS it works (i.e. incoming calls to iOS).

Issue is when I make an outgoing call from iOS to desktop, it doesn't work.

Below are the server logs, so I think call is getting connected...

> Received message: {"id":"incomingCall","from":"qqq"}
>
> spec:   {"audio":true,"video":{"width":640,"framerate":15}}
>
> chrome: {"audio":true,"video":{"optional":[{"minWidth":640},{"maxWidth":640},{"minFramerate":15},{"maxFramerate":15}]}}
>
> Sending message:{"id":"incomingCallResponse","from":"qqq","callResponse":"accept","sdpOffer”:”huge text, so removed”}
>
> Received message: {"id":"startCommunication","sdpAnswer":"huge text, so removed”}

When call is clicked I'm doing below on iOS:

```
[peerConnection offerForConstraints:[self defaultOfferConstraints] completionHandler:^(RTCSessionDescription * _Nullable sdp, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    
    [peerConnection setLocalDescription:sdp completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
    }];
    
    
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
        NSDictionary *registerMessage = @{
                                          @"id": @"call",
                                          @"from": @"qqq",
                                          @"to": @"www",
                                          @"sdpOffer" : sdp.description,
                                          };
        NSData *messageData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:registerMessage
                                                              options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                error:nil];
        NSString *messageString =
        [[NSString alloc] initWithData:messageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [webSocket send:messageString];
    }];
}];
```

and after I get accept response I do below,

```
if ([answerID isEqualToString:@"callResponse"]) {
    NSString *answerRespose = [wssMessage objectForKey:@"response"];
    if ([answerRespose isEqualToString:@"accepted"]) {
        description = [[RTCSessionDescription alloc] initWithType:RTCSdpTypeAnswer sdp:sdpAnswer];
        [peerConnection setRemoteDescription:description completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            
        }];
    }
}
```

I'm also taking care of ICECandidates...

As incoming works without any issue, I'm assuming that no mistake was made in creating stream.
Am I missing something for outgoing call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it out.
Issue was with ICECandidates, I came to know that adding ICECandidate after setting remote description works.
Made an array ICECandidates collected from web socket and added them once I got remote RemoteDescription :)

I hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: I'm having trouble when the guest video doesn't show up, everything seems to work, ICECandidate has been transmitted. can you help me!

Comment: did you try doing this??
"Made an array ICECandidates collected from web socket and added them once I got remote RemoteDescription :)"

Comment: I did that.I stopped the app while processing ice

Comment: projects about calling the kurento user group seem to be quite old, 
I am quite stuck when dealing with this issue

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply, I'm not sure what you mean by "stopped the app while processing ice"
add brake point on "addIceCandidate" calls and "setRemoteDescription"....

addIceCandidates should be called only after setRemoteDescription, this is what I have done....